# how to find the first recurrring character in a string using java 8 stream without intermediate terminal operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, state-monad

> I used the below example code only to illustrate the problem with Java 8 stream API. I am not expecting workaround to the given code but the explanation why accumulator function is not possible/provided in Stream.

I want to get the first recurring character in a string without using the intermediate terminal operation or shared mutation using Java 8 Stream api. I can do this with [RxJava scan operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) without pain. **The Scan/accumulator basically enable me to get hold of the previous element in the stream and I would be able to return my own type as the previous element from the scan. I see there are no possibilities with Java 8 stream but wanted to know why?** What is the problem in implementing the scan/accumulator operation in Stream?

**Issues with the workaround to achieve this:**

1. If I use the terminal operation then all of my inputs are processed which is unnecessary
2. If I use mutation the code cannot be parallelized or bring more issues if someone uses stream.parallel.

**given** - String str = "rtydydret";

**output** - y - because y is the first repeating character in the string.

Imperative example to achieve this: -

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (char charecter : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (list.contains(charecter)) {
            System.out.println(charecter);
            break;
        } else {
            list.add(charecter);
        }
    }
```

I also do not want to use below code as it uses terminal operation which means it processed all the character in the string, that's bad.

```
Map<Character, Long> collect =  "abcsdnvs".chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
    collect.forEach( (x,y) -> System.out.println( "Key: " + x + " Val: " + y));

    Optional<Character> firstRepeat = collect.entrySet().stream().filter( (e) -> e.getValue() > 1).map(e -> e.getKey()).findFirst();
    System.out.println("First repeating:" + firstRepeat.orElse(null));
```

Any insight would be greatly helpful. Thanks.

Comment: how is `y` the first repeating character in the string `ertydydret`? :|

Comment: Thanks for taking look at my question but what you think is the first repeating character?

Comment: `e` I would assume, since its the first one and it's repeated later in the string

Comment: @Eugene you could define *first character* also as the one which has the least number of character between itself and the repetition

Comment: @Lino I guess that is a good point... if the OP confirms this

Comment: @Eugene In my requirement Y should be the output, but I do not know how to phrase the question so that it is more clear to everyone rather confusing.

Comment: but even the code that you wrote for `ertydydret` says `e` as the first one...

Comment: We can't help if you don't tell us how you expect `y` to be the result.

Comment: if all you care about is the first character how about a regex for this? `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w)(?=.*\\1)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("easdea");

        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }`

Comment: @Eugene or `"(.)(?=.*?\\1)"`…

Answer (score 1):

> I see there are no possibilities with Java 8 stream but wanted to know why?

Because that would make the language, specifically the part with streams, and map/filter/reduce, more complicated than what it is now.

And for nothing, considering that you can implement that without a problem, without using streams. It's a tradeoff between complexity of the language and convenience it brings or doesn't bring.

Answer (score 1):

> I see there are no possibilities with Java 8 stream but wanted to know why?

I don't think you can achieve the result with parallelism, because you cannot determine which one come first when parallel processing unless you process all of your characters. (as you need to compare index of all result from parallel, if any, to determine which one comes first)

Without parallel-ready restriction (do not use parallel with this code), you can try this:

```
Set<Integer> filter = new HashSet<>();
OptionalInt c = str.chars().filter(e -> !filter.add(e)).findFirst();

if (c.isPresent()) {
   // You can access your repeated char here
   (char) c.getAsInt();
}
```

Comment: `OptionalInt` can be replaced by `Optional<Integer>`

Comment: that is not bad, *but* you are violating a stream rule called side-effects - run that in parallel and see in breaking.

Comment: As I said, this is not parallel-ready. `Without parallel-ready restriction`.

Comment: As I said, you cannot determine which repeated character come first in parallel stream. Did you really read my whole answer?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn Thanks for your time to explain. I can understand the issue with parallelism but want to understand why Java 8 Stream API is not providing the scan/accumulator operator in more detail. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways. The first one (which I would suggest is using a regex):

```
String input = "abcfra";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w)(?=.*\\1)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("input");

if (m.find()) {
     System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

The second one is a Stream-way of two loops actually:

```
int index = IntStream.range(0, input.length())
            .filter(x -> IntStream.range(x, input.length())
                    .filter(y -> input.indexOf(x) == input.indexOf(y))
                    .findAny()
                    .isPresent()
            )
            .findFirst()
            .getAsInt();

System.out.println(input.charAt(index));
```

And the third one, which you apparently don't like would be:

```
 char result = input.chars()
            .collect(
                    () -> new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>(),
                    (map, x) -> map.merge((char) x, 1, (oldV, newV) -> oldV + newV),
                    (left, right) -> {
                        for (Entry<Character, Integer> e : right.entrySet()) {
                            left.merge(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), (oldV, newV) -> oldV + newV);
                        }

                    }
            )
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getValue() > 1)
            .map(Entry::getKey)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse('?');
```

Which is basically close to the same way that you did. Just notice that you are trying to solve a problem that probably does not need solving to begin with (the performance one, going through all of the input and collecting to a `Map`).

Comment: Thanks for your time, I know there are workarounds but wanted to know why Java 8 stream API made this so complicated to achieve. If the Stream API can provide the Scan/accumulator function then the code becomes more readable also I can utilize the laziness by not looping the whole character in the stream if matched earlier.

Comment: your answer did not help me.